# Sending Data via Telnet using Python

Tags: python, telnet

i'm trying to send some floats using telnet. Currently i'm writting a python program to send those floats.

```
test=np.zeros(16)
for i in range(16):
    test[i]=(float)(i)

tn=telnetlib.Telnet("192.168.1.10","7")
for i in range(16):
    tn.write(str(test[i]))
```

When i execute this code i get a very strange outcome, the connection works well, and i send the first float (as a string) correctly. Then instead of sending the second number, the third etc i get something like

```
outcome0 = 0.0
outcome1 = 1.02.03.04.0
```

It seems than instead of sending one float in each iteration, after the first loop iteration  the strings are "concated".

If i use telnet from terminal and send some random numbers by hand it works well.

Is there some intuition about what is wrong with my code?
Is there any other way to sent floats via telnet? (maybe another programming language) (i have to sent a large number of floats)

Thnx :)

Comment: Your cast to a float is wrong, that’s C/C++/Java style. In Python it’s `float(i)`.

Comment: You aren't writing any newlines or other separators between your floats, so how can you possibly expect the other end to be able to distinguish them?  That the first one appeared to work is just an accident of timing.

Comment: @jasonharper Thnx for the quick reply, what kind of delimiter should i use? i tried adding +'\r\n' and +'\n' but it doesn't seem to work.

Josh thnx for the advice, it didn't produce any error and it worked fine but if that's the right way :)

Comment: You use whatever delimiter the other end is prepared to receive, of course.  It's impossible to be more specific than that when you've only posted half of the problem...